# How do I make a UIButton have the correct appearance with image and text?

Tags: swift, image, text, uibutton

I have a UIButton that has both an image and text in it. I am quite happy with its appearance except for when it is pressed.

Before it is pressed it looks like this:
[image]

After it is pressed it looks like this:
[image]

I am used to the appearance darkening the entire button when pressed, but for some reason when I have both an image and text is designates all the coloration to the image. I am quite aware that I can just make the entire button an image, but I am trying to keep this project as away from that style as possible. All of my other button are created with no images.

Is there any way to make the entire button darken as it normally would as it is currently setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the UIButton to Custom type (no System type) and change that properties:

```
self.yourButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
```

If I get what you want try with that code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}


@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) { 
    //Touch Up Inside action
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

@IBAction func buttonReleased(sender: UIButton) { 
    //Touch Down action
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

}
```

Normal:

[image]

Pressed:

[image]

Comment: This prevents the button from highlighting at all. I want the entire button to darken as it does when the entire button is an image.

Comment: The other option is any way to make the text highlight along with the image.

Comment: Could you post an example of what you want?

Comment: Ok, so this answer and a small amount of experimenting got what I wanted. I wouldn't mind have the entire button highlight instead of just the text/image, but all of my text button are functioning this way still. If you know how to make the whole button highlight, that would be great still!

Comment: I want the entire button to darken and not just the contained items.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I suppose I just got stuck in a stupid mindset here. Happy Holidays!

Comment: Happy holidays to you too:)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to match the text's highlight color:

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: UIControlState.highlighted)
```

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I thought this I thought this looked choppy in the past, but now that I am digging into buttons more it is a reasonable solution.